# JSON to alterable txt then back to JSON

Tags: python, json, file

I have a JSON file that I had to change every instance of the string [1] to _e. To solve this I saved the file as a text file then altered it with this python code.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput('reactions.json', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
    print(line.replace('[0]', '_c'), end='')
    print(line.replace('[1]', '_e'), end='')


with open('reactions.json') as data_file:    
data_reactions = json.load(data_file)
```

This worked like a charm, but once I rename the file extension to txt, the file can no longer can be saved as a JSON and read properly. Is there a way to convert back? I noticed saving it as a txt file seemed to remove the ENTER delimiters... I think.

Comment: Python doesn't care about file extensions, so something else is wrong with the file

Comment: The editor must have changed something in the file. Test with jsonlint.com

Comment: What are you using to read the JSON file? as others mentioned it may no longer be valid JSON. I would also recommend using the JSON library to edit the data natively before dumping it out to file again.

Comment: I took a look at jsonlint. My file is too large (37 Mb) and the website completely crashes when I copy it.

Comment: Code I am using --->                                                                                                                                 with open('reactions.json') as data_file:    
    data_reactions = json.load(data_file)

[*data_reactions]